I'm making a Django website using restapi ecommerce website during create subcategory I'm facing problem
this is my error I'm facing during create subcategory subcategory is created in database but after that I'm redirecting it to subcategory details it is giving this error...
This is my views.py
def subcategory_list(request, category_id):
    subcategories = Subcategory.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
    return render(request, 'category/subcategory_list.html', {'subcategories': subcategories})

def subcategory_create(request, category_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubcategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            subcategory = form.save(commit=False)
            subcategory.category_id = category_id
            subcategory.save()
            # Redirect to the subcategory details page with both category_id and subcategory_id
            return redirect('subcategory-details', category_id=category_id, pk=subcategory.pk)
    else:
        form = SubcategoryForm()
    return render(request, 'category/subcategory_create.html', {'form': form})

def subcategory_detail(request, category_id, pk):
    # Retrieve the parent category if needed
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    
    # Retrieve the subcategory
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategory, pk=pk)

    # Render the subcategory detail template with the retrieved data
    return render(request, 'category/subcategory_detail.html', {'category': category, 'subcategory': subcategory})

def subcategory_update(request, subcategory_id):
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategory, pk=subcategory_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubcategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=subcategory)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('subcategory-details', subcategory_id=subcategory_id)
    else:
        form = SubcategoryForm(instance=subcategory)
    return render(request, 'category/subcategory_update.html', {'form': form, 'subcategory': subcategory})

def subcategory_delete(request, subcategory_id):
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategory, pk=subcategory_id)
    category_id = subcategory.category.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subcategory.delete()
        return redirect('category-details', category_id=category_id)
    return render(request, 'category/subcategory_delete.html', {'subcategory': subcategory}) 

i got error here please help to fix error and this is my urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', category_list, name='category-list'),
    path('create/', category_create, name='category-create'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', category_update, name='category-update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', category_delete, name='category-delete'),
    path('<int:category_id>/details', category_detail, name='category-details'),
    path('<int:category_id>/subcategories/create/', subcategory_create, name='subcategory-create'),
    path('<int:category_id>/subcategories/list/', subcategory_list, name='subcategory-list'),
    # path('<int:category_id>/subcategories/<int:pk>/details/', subcategory_detail, name='subcategory-details'),
    path('subcategories/<int:pk>/details/', subcategory_detail, name='subcategory-details'),
    path('subcategories/<int:pk>/update/', subcategory_update, name='subcategory-update'),
    path('subcategories/<int:pk>/delete/', subcategory_delete, name='subcategory-delete'),
    
]


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

I don't see path for /categories/<number>/subcategories/create/ in urls.py  - you have only /<number>/subcategories/create/. Probably you have wrong url in HTML.
